# Are HASH values in Perl essentially memory locations?

Tags: perl, hash, reference

I have an issue.
If I assign a value of one hash (Hash A) to another hash (Hash B), and then change that value of Hash B, Hash A also changes.  How do I avoid that?

E.g.

```
$hashB{a}{b}{c} = 5;

$hashA{a}{b} = $hashB{a}{b};

$hashA{a}{b}{c} = 7;
```

Now `$hashB{a}{b}{c} = 7`!  I want the hash to to hold the original value.

How do I do that?

Comment: If by "HASH values" you mean references: Yes.

Comment: Related: https://p3rl.org/REF

Comment: You're mistaken. `$hashA{$a}{$b}{$c}{$d}` contains 5. `$hashA{$a}{$b}{$c}{$d} = $hashB{$a}{$c}{$d}` only copies the value 5, not the reference.

Comment: [Cannot reproduce.](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/7@0OFWhuKQoM7nEmgvELk8sysvMSy@25uLKrVTQUEnUUVBJAuJkIE7RVLBVKCzXSFRIUkhWSNG0BitRzUgsznDUUQDTTkBBLhUwq1olsbZaJRmIU2qB@kxhEo4QiSRkSUwd@FSbAyULijLzSrDo01FQislTsub6/x8A "Perl 5 – Try It Online") Try writing a [mcve] that shows the unexpected behavior.

Comment: Thanks, all.  I determined that I was getting too cute with the hashes.

Comment: Thanks, all.  I determined that I was getting too cute with the hashes.  I created, for lack of a better term, a 4-level hash, where the 4th index was the 3rd value, so $hashA{$a}[$b}{$c}[$d} was $hashA{$a}{$b}{$c}{$hashA{$a}{$b}{$c}}.  I would then create hashB, which had one more level, and assign hashA level 3 to hashB level 4, and hashA level 4 to hashB level 5.  Then, if I changed hashB level 5, it also changed hashA level 4.  If I split hashA into two differently named hashes, one with three levels, one with 4, and the same for hashB (4 and 5), the assignments don't run over each other.

Answer (score 5):

> *Are HASH values in Perl essentially memory locations?*

Yes, but you're protected from directly accessing the memory. We refer to them as "references". A "hash of hashes" is really a hash of references to other hashes. Perl will automatically create the intermediate hashes for you, a process known as "autovivification".

```
my %hashB;
$hashB{a}{c}{d} = 5;
print $hashB{a}{c}{d};
```

Let's expand out this example to make all the autovivification explicit. I'll use simple letters rather than variables so we don't have to define them.

```
my %hashB;

# $hashB{a}{c}{d} = 5;
my $hashD = { d => 5 };
my $hashC = { c => $hashD };
$hashB{a} = $hashC;

# print $hashB{a}{c}{d};
$hashC = $hashB{a};
$hashD = $hashC->{c};
print $hashD->{d};
```

This is all the work Perl is doing behind the scenes. Each level of nesting is its own hash.

Note that hash values are only ever scalars, single values. If you try this...

```
$hashB{q} = %hashQ;
```

...you'll get something very odd. In this case Perl tries to treat `%hashQ` as a scalar. A hash as a scalar is the number of buckets in the hash, something like `1/8`. Not very useful.

What you can do is this.

```
$hashB{q} = \%hashQ;
```

This takes a reference to `%hashQ`, like a pointer in other languages, and assigns it to `$hashB{q}`.

Now if you make changes to keys in `$hashB{q}` you'll actually be changing `%hashQ`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.10;

my %hashQ = ( foo => 23 );
my %hashB;

# assign a reference to %hashQ
$hashB{q} = \%hashQ;
say $hashB{q}{foo};     # 23
say $hashQ{foo};     # 23

# change %hashQ via a reference
$hashB{q}{foo} = 42;
say $hashB{q}{foo};  # 42
say $hashQ{foo};     # 42

# change %hashQ directly
$hashQ{foo} = 99;
say $hashB{q}{foo};  # 99
say $hashQ{foo};     # 99
```

---

On the other hand, simple string and number values in Perl are copied. So in your example...

```
$hashB{$a}{$c}{$d} = 5; # assign 5

$hashA{$a}{$b}{$c}{$d} = $hashB{$a}{$c}{$d}; # COPY 5

$hashA{$a}{$b}{$c}{$d} = 7; # assign 7
```

`$hashB{$a}{$c}{$d}` remains 5 because its value, 5, was copied.

On the other hand, if you did this...

```
$hashB{$a}{$c}{$d} = 5; # assign 5

$hashA{$a}{$b}{$c} = $hashB{$a}{$c}; # copy a reference

$hashA{$a}{$b}{$c}{$d} = 7; # assign 7
```

Now `$hashB{$a}{$c}{$d}` is 7 because you copied a reference to the hash in `$hashB{$a}{$c}`.

---

For more, see...

- [Perl Reference Tutorial](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html)
- [Perl References](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html)
- [Perl Data Structures Cookbook](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html)

Comment: Re "*This takes a reference to %hashQ, like a pointer in other languages*", A reference is simply a pointer one can't modify. Some languages have one, some have the other, and some have both

Comment: @ikegami "Can't modify" in the sense that you can't scribble arbitrarily over the memory it points to, but Perl references do so much more. There's memory management via reference counting. Various flags. Size and length tracking. "Magic". Etc... To a C programmer, Perl references are better described as pointers to fully memory managed and encapsulated structs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174758/discussion-between-schwern-and-ikegami).

Comment: I think it's more accurate to say: "*"Can't modify" in the sense that you can't scribble arbitrarily over the memory it points to. Forbidding pointers allows Perl to keep track of what memory is being used and automatically free it when its no longer used. This is all done behind the scenes when taking a reference and erasing them*"